# Is there a better way to disable a button when posting data in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

In my projects at the moment, I use something along these lines for AJAX forms.

```
$scope.posting = false;
$scope.submitForm = function(form){

    log(form);
    log((!form.$invalid) ? 'Is valid' : 'Contains errors');

    $scope.posting = true;

    $http.post('/modules/ajax/addModule', $scope.module)
        .success(function(data, status, headers, config){

            data = data.data;

            log(data);

            $scope.posting = false;

            if(data.error){
                alert(data.message);
            }

        })
        .error(function(data, status, headers, config){

            data = data.data;

            log(data);

            $scope.posting = false;
        });
}
```

and on the submit button, `<input ng-disabled="form.$invalid || posting" ... />`

Whilst it's not much to type code, manually switching the bool value seems a little non Angular to me. Is there anyway to tell if an $http.post is still active?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing was adding this code to my global JS file.

```
app.run(function($rootScope, $http) {
    $http.defaults.transformRequest.push(function (data) {
        $rootScope.$isPosting = true;
        return data;
    });
    $http.defaults.transformResponse.push(function(data){ 
        $rootScope.$isPosting = false;
        return data;
    }) 
});
```

Then I  can just use

```
<a ng-disabled="isPosting" ...
```

Answer (score 0):

just write a directive which will disable and enable the button on http calls, like below

```
app.directive('onClick', function() {
  return {
    scope: {
      onClick: '&'
    },
    link: function(scope, iElement, iAttrs) {
      iElement.bind('click', function() {
        iElement.prop('disabled',true);
        scope.onClick().finally(function() {
          iElement.prop('disabled',false);
        })
      });
    }
  };
});
```

note : onClick function should return a promise for this to work

Checkout this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/YsDVTlQ8TUxbKAEYNw7L?p=preview) to see it in action

I use [angular-ladda](http://blog.remotty.com/angular-ladda/) for button with spinner while call is in progress